# Targeted .NET Framework version change

Tags: visual-studio-2012, target-framework

How do I go about changing the version for the targeted version of the .NET Framework from 4.5.1 to 4.5 in Visual Studio 2012?

Answer (score 3):

You can usually select your desired target framework within the application properties. Your setup may be slightly different, my Visual Studio installation is using the C# development settings by default, and the example image below is from a `WPF` project (on the off chance yours is different).

Either right-click on your project in the `Solution Explorer` and select `Properties`->`Application`, or select `Properties` from the main toolbar in Visual Studio, and select the `Application` tab. You should be able to select the target framework.

[image]

If you can't select the particular framework you're after, the issue may be slightly different.

Comment: That looks rather similar in `Visual Studio 2012` and 2013.

Comment: @AxelKemper I don't see the Application option at all.

Comment: That might be a matter of the project type. I've tried it with `c#` console applications for `2012` and `2013`. `Alt+F7` gets me in the property form. `Application` is the top category as shown in Chris' answer.

Comment: Certainly appears for me in 2012 (both Ultimate & Pro running Updated 4), I think Axel may be correct about project type (perhaps also environment configuration/version).

Comment: @Chris Please upvote the anwser if it worked for you so that others would prefer it

Comment: Yeah, the Application option just doesn't appear if it's a web solution... WEIRD!

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the **Microsoft .NET Framework x.x.x Developer Pack** then only it will be visible under the Target Framework dropdown

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! I right clicked on my project - select Edit Project File - Went and looked for the `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>` - then saved and reloaded the project.

Comment: I right click on the website and I don't see "Edit Project File."

Answer (score 0):

Check the target framework of the project you created.  To fix your problem change it to .NET Framework version.

To do this right-click your project and select Properties. On the **Compile** tab, **Click Advance Compile Options...** and set the **Target Framework dropdown** to .NET Framework version.

[image]

Comment: This property Layout is for VS 2012. Changing The Framework from client profile to Just .Net Framework also Fixes the issue of Crystal report viewer not showing in the toolbox

Comment: This dialog isn't visible in VS2012 for web solutions... it's just not there.