# framework conversion in control panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, web-hosting

I'm using visual studio 2012 and have account in hostgator for web hosting .net.
visual  studio 2012 uses 4.5 framework and in hostgator parallel panel I tried to change the version of framework in  asp.net setting but only version '4.0.30319.34209' and '2.0.50727.5483' is available.I need some tips to which version of visual studio suitable for all hosting domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing the version of .NET with the version of the CLR.  It's an easy thing to confuse.  Your hosting platform supports two versions of the CLR 4.0 and 2.0.

.NET 2.0 and .NET 3.5 run on version 2.0 of the CLR.
.NET 4.0, 4.5, 4.5.1, and 4.5.2 will run on version 4.0 of the CLR.

You can use Visual Studio 2012 to create web applications targeting .NET 2.0 - 4.5.x, so you're fine.

If this is a new application, I'd recommend targeting the latest *released* version of the framework (4.5.2) which will run on CLR 4.0.  So in your hostgator set target framework to 4.0.  Visual Studio should default to creating a web application in the latest .net version, but you can always check/change via the Properties window for the project.

[image]

(Screenshot taken from: [Targeted .NET Framework version change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22771598/visual-studio-2012-targeted-framework-version-change))

Comment: Thanks.I created a sample website and uploaded it into httpdocs folder.But I caught error in web.config file.how to recover it.

Comment: Configuration Error. Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Comment: That sounds like a different problem.  You should close this issue and ask a new question for that error message.  BTW, off hand I think that's an iis issue

Comment: Internet Information Service is Microsoft's Web Server.  It's what hosts/runs asp.net web sites: http://www.iis.net/